# fseek for fd (int fd instead of FILE*)

Tags: c, file

Is there an equivalent of fseek for fd? I've been using int fds for a very long time, and want to use fseek... but I know there is no seek function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See the POSIX function [lseek(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek):

> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> off_t
> lseek(int fildes, off_t offset, int whence);
> ```
>
> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> The `lseek()` function repositions the offset of the file descriptor `fildes` to the argument `offset`, according to the directive `whence`.  The argument `fildes` must be an open file descriptor.

Comment: Anyone know the history of the `lseek` function, particularly the reason for the `l`? My suspicion has always been that the `l` stood for `long`, since the original offset argument type was `long`, and in the days of 16-bit `int` types, a `seek` protofunction that took an `int` argument for the offset would have quickly become useless for working with files.

Comment: @R..: John Lion's UNIX V6 Source (found it online) does indicate that Version 6 only had a `seek` taking `int` offset.  A Version 7 manual (also found online) shows no `seek` in sight and instead `lseek` taking `long` offset.  I would just be guessing too, but your guess seems good to me.