# Contents of file not being printed in terminal

Tags: c, file, fwrite

Hi I am trying to read from a file and print it on terminal. But `fwrite()` does not print anything. Can anyone please help! I cannot see the output from the file on the terminal. After debugging all I can see is program is not entering into while loop used before `fwrite()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 128

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int BATT_fd, ret_write, ret_read, i;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];      

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf ("\nUsage: cp file1 file2\n");
        return 1;
    }

    BATT_fd = open (argv [1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU);

    if (BATT_fd == -1) 
    {
        perror ("open");
        return 2;
    }

 printf("\n file opened successfully with file desc %d\n", BATT_fd);
 printf("enter data into file\n");
 scanf("%[^\n]", buffer);

     if((ret_write = write (BATT_fd, &buffer, BUF_SIZE)) == 0)
     { 
         printf("nothing is write");    
     }
     else if((ret_write = write (BATT_fd, &buffer, BUF_SIZE)) == -1)
     { 
         printf("write error"); 
     }
     else
     {
         printf("wrote %d characters to file\n", ret_write);
         printf("address writeen is %x\n", buffer[i]);
     }

     if((ret_read = read(BATT_fd, &buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)
     { 
        perror("read"); 
        return 4;
     }
     else
     {
        while((ret_read = read (BATT_fd, &buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 1, ret_read, stdout);
        }
     }

 close (BATT_fd);

 return 0;
}
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before reading data from file, you need to move current position in file to the begining. That's because your write operations have moved current position to the end of file, so there is nothing left for reading ;).

see fseek

**EDIT:**

lseek would be better in your case (see comments)

Comment: Also, the logic of the `if` preceeding it is incorrect: it should be `if(ret_read` [...] `<=0)` for the error condition.

Comment: Yeah, right. I've stopped investigation on first mistake :)

Comment: Thank you guys, but it seems fseek requires file pointer as 1st argument, but here i used integer(BATT_fd) to store file descriptor. Is there any way around so that I can use my integer descriptor with fseek or should I change BATT_fd type to FILE* and change open, read and write to fopen, fread and fwrite?

Comment: use lseek then (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405825/fseek-for-fd-int-fd-instead-of-file)